# How to automatically send cloud message to app in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I wanted to know if it was possible to do the following :

When firebase's database gets a value, it checks if the value is either 1 or 0, if it is one , then it will send a cloud message to the android app saying that 'We have got 1 value'. If it is possible, please tell me how to do it . Also, I've already setup the firebase implementation in android studio, so no issue in that.

Comment: I think you might want to have a look at [notifying users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Frank van Puffelen, I will surely look into it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the basic nature of firebase and the whole point of modern sync systems such as firebase and AWS' Amplify.

1. Make a (for example) iOS or droid app
2. Install the Firebase libraries
3. Create a Firebase account and app
4. Learn fully how to program Firebase
5. Now, if a value changes in the cloud, it will change on all connected apps in realtime.

In answer to the question in your title you don't "send a message". You just change the value somewhere and it changes everywhere.

If you are thinking more of "messages", what you want is PubNub, which is the basic "messaging" system of the planet. If you're thinking more of "moving things in sync" (as in a game), that's Photon.